# C++: Generate file on remote machine and transfer to local machine

Tags: c++

i am trying to create a C++ program on Windows machine which has to execute a program on remote machine, transfer the generated file to local machine. The remote machine is also windows.

Is there any efficient method to implement it without using MFC? Is it possible to do it without server/client component?

Regards,
Adil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend coding your solution since other solutions already exist. One of them is [Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), which is pretty popular in *nix circles.

A Windows friendly version also exists, and it's called [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp).

Unless you're trying to improve your skills, or have the time, or you believe you can do better, stick with proven solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of windows remote shell solutions that will allow you to do this without programming. You can also use a remote desktop client.

Answer (score 0):

use ftp command from c++ or Cleint/Server.